# Block cipher mode of operation with beyond-birthday-bound security

Tags: block-cipher, reference-request, modes-of-operation, birthday-attack

I am looking for block cipher modes of operation that are secure even when the number of blocks encrypted exceeds the birthday bound.

Comment: Hmm, would counter mode encryption work, provided you'd never repeat the counter? Just thinking out loud here.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, security is still lost after the birthday bound, because ciphertext collisions give you information about what the plaintext cannot be.

Comment: @otus Can we assume that this is then a property of the block cipher itself? Or could we construct a new cipher out of it with a higher bound? I'd presume that could be possible, but it would probably be rather complex / inefficient. I'm not sure that I would call that a "mode of operation".

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, it follows from block size and counter mode. You'd have to construct a larger cipher or use another mode to get better bounds.

Comment: @otus How much information is leaked? Is the information leaked of a form usable to an attacker?

Comment: Some modes are presented here: https://www.cs.ru.nl/~bmennink/slides/croatia17b.pdf

Answer (score 6):

It is not a standard mode of operation and I do not know if anyone uses it in practice, but one option is double encryption using counter mode and a non-repeating counter. That is, doing $E_{k_1}(i) \oplus E_{k_2}(i) \oplus p$. The sum of two PRPs is a PRF with better bounds than one. The bound is basically $O(2^{2n/3})$  rather than $O(2^{n/2})$. See [The Sum of Two PRPs is a secure PRF](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-45539-6_34).

For example, with a 64-bit block size that means something like going from encrypting 32 gigabytes before attacker advantage to encrypting 32 terabytes instead.

Comment: Well double encryption and dual keys is indeed inefficient but it isn't as bad as I thought it could be. Still not a common mode of encryption, using a cipher with a larger block size could be preferable.

Comment: After reading the question, I also immediately thought of dual-ctr as the most simple option, followed by XEX with dual-ctr Xs and a third key